# Should I use a `&` when selecting direct children using `>`?

Tags: css, less

While writing less, I noticed that the following two snippets:

#### A.

```css
.parent-el {
   & > .direct-child { ... }
}
```

#### B.

```css
.parent-el {
   > .direct-child { ... }
}
```

will produce exactly the same css:

```css
.parent-el > .direct-child {
   ...
}
```

I have several questions:

- Are there any differences between **A** and **B**?
- Is this intentional and by design?
- Which one should I use, and why?

Comment: it's exaclty the same as without `>` ... `.A { .B}` is the same as `.A { & .B}` so yes it's by design, since less is made like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Are there any differences between A and B?

There will be no difference in the compiled CSS. The `&` in LESS is replaced with the outer selector in compiled CSS. So, **A** is really the same as doing:

```
.parent-el {
    .parent-el > .direct-child { ... }
}
```

This, of course, is redundant and defeats the purpose of using LESS in the first place.

## Is this intentional and by design?

The `&` really is not used as I believe it was intended in your example. A good example of using a `&` in LESS would be something like this:

```
.parent-el {
    // define .parent-el styles
    &__child { 
        // define .parent-el__child styles
    }
}
```

In the above example, the `&` allows you to shorten the declaration of `.parent-el__child`.

## Which one should I use, and why?

You should use **B**. In this case, using the `&` is redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

the use of the "&" is optional, when you insert the selector inside another becomes implicit that the intention is to start from your "parent".

Although I get less code when we do not use "&" I prefer to use it because the code is cleaner